# MSMQ between WCF services in a load balanced enviroment

Tags: wcf, msmq, msmq-wcf

I'm thinking of adding a queue function in a product based on a bunch of WCF services. I've read some about MSMQ, first I thought that was what I needed but I'm not sure and are considering to just put the queue in a database table. I wonder if somone here got some feedback on which way to go.

Basicly I'm planning to have a facade WCF service called over http. The facade service should only write all incoming messages to a queue to give a fast response to the calling system. The messages in the queue should then be processed by another component, either a WCF service or a Windows service depending om my choice of queue.

The product is running in a load balanced enviroment with 2 to n web servers.

The options I'm considering and the questions I got are:

1. To let the facade WCF write to a MSMQ and then have anothther WCF service reading from this queue to do the processing of the messages. What I don't feel confident about for this alternative from what I've read is how this will work in a load balanced enviroment.

1A. Where should the MSMQ(s) be placed? One on each web server? One on a separate server? Mulitple on a separate server? (not considering need of redundance and that data in rare cases could be lost and re-sent)

1B. How it the design affected if I want the system redundant? I'd like to be alble to lose a server (it never comes up online again) holding the MSMQ without losing the data in that queue. From what I've read about MSMQ that leaves me to the only option of placing the MSMQ on a windows cluster. Is that correct? (I'd like to avoid using a windows cluster fo this).

1. The second design alternative is to let the facade WCF service write the queue to a database. Then have two or more Windows services to do the processing of the queue. I don't have any questions on this alternative. If you wonder why I don't pick this one as it seems simpler to me then it is because I'd like to build this not introducing any windows services to the solution, that I beleive the MSMQ got functionality I don't want to code myself and I'm also curious about using MSMQ as I've never used it before.

Best Regards
Håkan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading some more on the subjet I haver decided to not use MSMQ. It seems like I really got no reason to go down this road. I need this to be non-transactional and as I understand it none of the journaling or dead letter techniques will help me with my redundancy requirement.

All my components will be online most of the time (maybe a couple of hours per year when they got access problems).

The MSQM will only add complexity to the exciting solution, another technique and maybe another server to keep track of.

To get full redundance to prevent data loss in MSMQ I will need a windows cluster or implement send/recieve to multiple identical queues. I don't want to do either of those.

All this lead me to front my recieving application with a WCF facade accepting http calls writing to a database queue. This database is already protected from data loss. The queue will be polled by muliple active instances of a Windows Servce containing all the heavy business logic. With low process priority these services could be hosted on the already existing nodes used by the load balaced web application. If I got time to use MSMQ or if I needed it for another reason in my application I might change my decision.

Answer (score 2):

OK, so you're not using WCF with MSMQ integration, you're using WCF to create MSMQ messages as an end-product. That simplifies things to "how do I load balance MSMQ?"

The arrangement you use is based on what works best for you.
You could have multiple webservers sending messages to a remote queue on a central machine.
Instead you could have a webservers putting messages in local queues with a central machine polling the queues for new arrivals.

You don't need to cluster MSMQ to make it resilient. You can instead make your code resilient so that it copes with lost messages using dead letter queues, transactional queues, journaling, and so on. Hardware clustering is the easy option :-)

- [Load-balancing MSMQ - a brief
  discussion](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/johnbreakwell/archive/2009/03/19/load-balancing-msmq-a-brief-discussion.aspx)
- [Oil and water - MSMQ transactional
  messages and load balancing](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/johnbreakwell/archive/2008/11/18/oil-and-water-msmq-transactional-messages-and-load-balancing.aspx)

Comment: You mention two options, a central queue or local queues with a central reciever. I'll read the links you provided maybe they will help. I'll let you know. As I'm new to how to do the WCF-MSMQ thing I dont' know how what I'm thinking of differs from "WCF with MSMQ integration".

Comment: "WCF with MSMQ integration" means using MSMQ as the transport protocol instead of HTTP for delivering a WCF call to the service.

Comment: How does that differ other then the "WCF MSQM integration" is saving me some coding?

Comment: "WCF with MSMQ integration" uses MSMQ to perform webservice operation X. Operation X doesn't have to be anything to do with MSMQ.
You desire to use WCF to create an MSMQ message that will be consumed by another process - here operation X is the creation of an MSMQ message.